# SQL MERGE Table with tableName

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, dynamic-sql

I would like have a generic procedure to Update my look Up Table.

```
CREATE TYPE S_Reference.[ReferenceType] as TABLE (
    [Id] SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Code] VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    [Rank] SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK([Rank]>0),
    [Description] VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [Base] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [S_Reference].[P_B_ReferenceMerge]
    @Values [ReferenceType] READONLY,
    @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
AS

DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(200)
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName 

    MERGE INTO @SQLQuery Ori
    USING 
        @Values New
    ON (Ori.[Id] = New.[Id])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET Ori.[Code] = New.[Code],
                Ori.[Rank] = New.[Rank],
                Ori.[Description] = New.[Description],
                Ori.[Base] = New.[Base]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Ori.[Id] , Ori.[Code], Ori.[Rank],Ori.[Description] ,Ori.[Base])
        Values (New.[Id] , New.[Code], New.[Rank],New.[Description] ,New.[Base]);
RETURN 0
```

But I don't know how to use the "tableName" ?
I get an error on Ori.[Id], I think the problem comes from

```
 SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName 
        MERGE INTO @SQLQuery Ori
```

Comment: WHy are you trying to do this with dynamic SQL and what are you actually trying to do? MERGE INTO SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLENAME is not the correct syntax

Comment: @BS123 I want to pass a Table of last values by the parameter AAValues. And pass the destination table by the parameter AATablename. The procedure has to update or insert the new values in the tableName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can help this is how I did. By this way You can manage easily the values in your look up (reference or enum in c#).

First the procedure:

```
    CREATE TYPE S_Reference.[ReferenceType] AS TABLE (
    [Id] SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Code] VARCHAR(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    [Rank] SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK([Rank]>0),
    [Description] VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [Base] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [S_Reference].[P_M_ReferenceMerge]
    @Values  S_Reference.[ReferenceType] READONLY,
    @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
AS

CREATE TABLE #NewValues (
    [Id] SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Code] VARCHAR(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    [Rank] SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK([Rank]>0),
    [Description] VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [Base] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

Insert INTO #NewValues
select * From @Values

DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLQuery = 
'DELETE 
FROM ' + @TableName + '
WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT [Id]
                FROM ' + @TableName + '
                EXCEPT
                SELECT [Id]
                FROM #NewValues)

MERGE INTO ' + @TableName + ' Ori 
USING #NewValues New 
ON (Ori.[Id] = New.[Id]) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET Ori.[Code] = New.[Code], 
        Ori.[Rank] = New.[Rank], 
        Ori.[Description] = New.[Description], 
        Ori.[Base] = New.[Base] 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([Id] , [Code], [Rank], [Description] ,[Base]) 
    Values (New.[Id] , New.[Code], New.[Rank], New.[Description] ,New.[Base]);'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
RETURN 0
```

Usage

```
INSERT INTO 
    @VALUES([Id],[Code],[Rank],[Description] ,[Base])
Values
    (1,'EUR',1,'EUR',0),
    (2,'GBP',2,'GBP',0),
    (3,'USD',3,'USD',0)
EXEC [S_Reference].[P_M_ReferenceMerge]
    @Values = @VALUES,
    @TableName = 'S_Reference.T_R_Currency'
DELETE FROM @VALUES
```